# Oracle - bind_aware hint not showing as is_bind_aware in v$sql result

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, oracle12c

We use a lot of `/*+ bind_aware */` hints in my office, and this morning I decided to do a quick test to see if they work as I expect.

I started with a commonly used table we'll call `person`, and a simple query on it like so:

```
SELECT /* foo */ /*+ bind_aware */ * FROM person WHERE person_id = :person;
```

But after running the above query, this was the result:

```
SELECT child_number, executions, buffer_gets, 
     is_bind_sensitive, is_bind_aware, is_shareable
     FROM v$sql 
     WHERE sql_text LIKE 'SELECT /* foo%';

CHILD_NUMBER  EXECUTIONS  BUFFER_GETS  IS_BIND_SENSITIVE  IS_BIND_AWARE  IS_SHAREABLE
           0           1           26                  N              N             Y
```

Alas, I expected `IS_BIND_AWARE = Y`.

There is a hybrid histogram on `person_id` as seen here:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, HISTOGRAM 
  FROM   ALL_TAB_COL_STATISTICS 
  WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'PERSON'
  AND COLUMN_NAME = 'PERSON_ID';

COLUMN_NAME  HISTOGRAM
  PERSON_ID     HYBRID
```

The `PERSON_ID` column is indexed and a unique identifier, but I still expect it to be bind aware. Why is this not the case?

Comment: if this is a unique identifier on this table, why would you expect the plan to change at all?  Meaning, I wouldn't expect it to be bind sensitive or bind aware.  The plan shouldn't change based on the person_id you bind in the query.

Comment: Well, I came across the following two articles and expected at least to see two cursors and forced cursor sharing. The cursor is shareable, but still not bind aware.
https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/why-are-there-more-cursors-in-11g-for-my-query-containing-bind-variables
https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/how-do-i-force-a-query-to-use-bind-aware-cursor-sharing

Comment: Bind sensitive cursor means it is a candidate for plan changing.  Bind aware are cursors that should actually change.  If you were pulling data for people that lived in a given state (where state = :state), and the data was very skewed, you might have a plan that changes depending on the bound state.  In your case, looking up a row based on a unique index (person_id) is going to have the same plan no matter what the person_id

Comment: Thanks, that helps; I wasn't aware of that distinction. Does this mean a query could be marked as bind aware even without the hint?

Comment: Yes, that is correct